# Proving $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ using uniform convergence theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, power-series

> Prove that
> $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$
> using uniform convergence theorem.

I already know that you can obtain quickly this equality using dominated convergence theorem or the $\sum \Vert f_n \Vert_1 < +\infty$ theorem.

Here is another method:

The function $x \mapsto \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x+1}$ is continuous on $]0,1]$ and in a neighborhood of $0$ we have that : $\left \vert \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x+1} \right \vert \sim_0 \vert \ln(x)\vert=_0\omicron\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt t}\right)$. Hence this function is Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Integrating by parts gives:
\begin{gather*}
\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x= \left[\ln(x)\ln(x+1)\right]^1_\varepsilon - \int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
= \ln(1)\ln(2) - \ln(\varepsilon)\ln(\varepsilon +1) -\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{gather*}
Then taking limits with $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Then noticing that for all $\vert x \vert < 1$:
$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^n}{n}$$
we get that:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{n-1}}{n}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Let $t\in [0,1[$. The power series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{n-1}}{n}$ is normally convergent in every compact intervals of the form $[0,t]$ which is included in the domain of convergence $]-1,1[$ of the series (it has radius of convergence equals to $1$) so the convergence is also uniform on that interval. Adding the fact that for all $n\ge 1$ the functions $x\mapsto \dfrac{(-1)^nx^{n-1}}{n}$ are continuous on $[0,t]$, it enables us to write:
$$\int_{0}^{t}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{n-1}}{n}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_{0}^{t} x^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n t^n}{n^2}.$$

Now the last step is to prove that:
$$\lim_{t\to 1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n t^n}{n^2}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}.$$
Enough to prove that the series of functions $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n t^n}{n^2}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

We remark that for all $n\ge 1$, the functions $t\mapsto \dfrac{(-1)^n t^n}{n}$ are continuous on $[0,1]$. 
Moreover, for all $t \in [0,1]$ : $\left\vert \dfrac{(-1)^n t^n}{n^2} \right\vert\le \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ which is the general term of a convergent series. That means that $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{+\infty} \sup_{t\in[0,1]} \left\vert \dfrac{(-1)^n t^n}{n^2} \right\vert< +\infty$ so the series of functions is normally convergent on $[0,1]$ so uniformly. And it gives the continuity of the series of functions on $[0,1]$.

Hence we can conclude that:
$$\lim_{t\to 1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n t^n}{n^2}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \lim_{t \to 1}\dfrac{(-1)^n t^n}{n^2} =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}.$$

Is that method where I tried to apply uniform convergence criterion, correct ? It seems that the last step is useless because the series of functions $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n t^n}{n^2}$ is well-defined for all $t\in [0,1]$. Also maybe at the step $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{n-1}}{n}$ we could have used the result about the uniform bound of the queue for the alternating series.

Thanks in advance!